# How to create new QualificationType on amazon mturk using C# API?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am trying to create a new QulaificationType for which the workers have to answer a question to gain the qualification.Below is my C# code. I am getting an error while using createQualificationType method in C# api. Please help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Amazon.WebServices.MechanicalTurk;
using Amazon.WebServices.MechanicalTurk.Domain;

namespace CreateHITExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static SimpleClient client = new SimpleClient();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateNewHIT();
        }

        static void CreateNewHIT()
        {
            **QuestionFormQuestion** question = new QuestionFormQuestion();
            question.IsRequired = true;
            question.QuestionIdentifier = "1";
            **ContentType qnContent = new ContentType();**

            QualificationType qualType = client.CreateQualificationType("MyQual2", string.Empty, "My Qualification Type", QualificationTypeStatus.Active, 0, **question**, "680", 600, true, 100);
            string qualTypeId = qualType.QualificationTypeId;
            Console.WriteLine("Created Qualification Type ID 2: {0}", qualTypeId);
        }
    }
}
```

I have to pass the question object as the parameter to CreateQualificationType method.
As you can see from the above piece of code, question object is of class QuestionFormQuestion.

Below are the class definitions that might be of some help.

**QuestionFormQuestion Class definition from AWS MTurk dotnet API:**

```
public class QuestionFormQuestion
    {
        public QuestionFormQuestion();

        public AnswerSpecificationType AnswerSpecification { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public bool IsRequiredSpecified { get; set; }
        **public ContentType QuestionContent { get; set; }**
        public string QuestionIdentifier { get; set; }
    }
```

The actual question text goes into the QuestionContent attribute, which is of type "ContentType".

**ContentType Class definition from AWS MTurk dotnet API:**

```
public class ContentType
    {
        public ContentType();

        [XmlChoiceIdentifier("ItemsElementName")]
        [XmlElement("Application", typeof(ApplicationContentType))]
        [XmlElement("Binary", typeof(BinaryContentType))]
        [XmlElement("FormattedContent", typeof(String))]
        [XmlElement("Text", typeof(String))]
        [XmlElement("Title", typeof(String))]
        public object[] Items { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("ItemsElementName")]
        [XmlIgnore]
        public ItemsChoiceType[] ItemsElementName { get; set; }
    }
```

I have to move the Actual Question sentence to the [XmlElement("Text", typeof(String))] element of the ContentType object. I dont know the syntax to do that. Please Help.

Comment: Unhandled Exception: Amazon.WebServices.MechanicalTurk.Exceptions.InvalidParamet
erValueException: The value "[com.amazon.mechanicalturk.common.types.Qualificati
onTestDTO@d9899ed5]" is not valid for the parameter Test.

Comment: Go ahead and edit all of that information into your question so that it's properly formatted and easier to read.

Comment: @Thomas please let me know if the updated question gives you enough information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same ValueException error message using the Ruby SDK until I discovered that (unlike ALL the API documentation examples, which showed XML was expected) **CreateHit was expecting a Hash, not XML for some parameters** (XML for Question, but Hash for QualificationRequirement for example).

In my case it was rejecting a QualificationRequirement when I supplied it XML like they show in the docs, but it worked when I provided it as a Hash.

But since the error message is the same, I suspect that may be what you are running into as well. (The error is language independent... it's not form your SDK, it's what is being returned from AWS when your SDK submits the HIT.)

```
# does NOT work:
usa_qualification = 'XML STRING LIKE AWS DOCS GIVE'

# DOES work:
usa_qualification = { 
  :QualificationTypeId => "00000000000000000071",
   :Comparator => "EqualTo",
   :LocaleValue => { :Country => "US"},

result = mturk.createHIT( :Title => title,
   ...
  :QualificationRequirement =>  usa_qualification , 
   ...
```